# programmatically setting up a vpn from PHP

Tags: ssh, vpn

I have a website in one place which needs to transmit information and ssh to a second server.  For security the second place doesn't like ssh in, they want vpn. I have seen postings on here for vpn from android, but is there anything for php under linux?

A command line utility would do it.  I want to:
scp a file over, ssh a script, get the output back.

Comment: I'm not sure if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11798606/php-post-data-over-vpn) would help?

Comment: It does help.  The question then becomes, can I get a vpn executable, put it up on my web server, and run it to connect to a remote site?  That's a separate question, but thanks, that posting was perfect.